# How can I use live reload in a public-facing ruby server?

Tags: ruby, livereload

I'm using the livereload plugin for guard in combination with the chrome extension. It's working nicely and my browser refreshes whenever a source file is changed.

It seems like Meteor has this functionality without requiring a chrome extension. Is there any similar library for the ruby world, to hot-push ui changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the browser plugin, use [Rack::LiveReload](https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload). It will send events to the browser via web sockets and cause the browser to reload when `watch`ed changes occur.